# Use find and set in aggregation pipeline to populate value in nested document based on list of ids

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

In this example doc, _id and myOtherId are Object Ids.

```
{
   _id: 1
   name: "Joe"
   myAreas: [
             {_id: 1a, isActive: false, myOtherId: 1a1, area: "Gaming"},
             {_id: 2a, isActive: false, myOtherId: 1a2, area: "Fishing"},
             {_id: 3a, isActive: false, myOtherId: 1a3, area: "Cooking"},
            ]
}
```

Let say I have a list of ids to change isActive to true.

```
activeIds = ['1a1', '1a3']
```

I need to create a way to update the nested documents if myOtherId is in the list of activeIds.  If it isn't on that list, it should change the value to false (assuming in the future I will set different areas as active.

This is what I have so far but it just converts everything to false.  Im using the aggregation pipeline approach.  I know I'm messing up on the $ operator, but cant seem to figure out the right syntax to make this work.  I also tried converting the activeIds list to a list of Object Ids like :
activeIds = [ObjectId('1a1'), ObjectId('1a3')]

```
await User.findByIdAndUpdate(1,
[
  {
    $set: {
           "myAreas.isActive": {
               $in: ["myAreas.$.myOtherId", activeIds],
                },
              },
            },
  ],
          { multi: true, new: true }
        );
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?  Is this even on the right track or am I completely off?

If I rewrite like this, it works but the issue here is it just updates the activeIds isActive prop to true and doesnt set the rest of the ids not on the list to false.

```
await User.updateMany(
  { _id: 1 },
  {
   $set: {
          "myAreas.$[elem].isActive": true,
         },
  },
  {
   arrayFilters: [{ "elem.myOtherId": { $in: activeIds} }],
   multi: true,
   new: true,
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like this with two arrayFilters:

```
   db.collection.update({},
    {
    $set: {
     "myAreas.$[x].isActive": "TRUE",
     "myAreas.$[y].isActive": "FALSE"
     }
    },
    {
     arrayFilters: [
     {
      "x.myOtherId": {
       $not: {
         $in: [
             "1a1",
             "1a2"
              ]
        }
      }
    },
     {
      "y.myOtherId": {
        $in: [
           "1a1",
           "1a2"
             ]
          }
        }
      ],
      multi: true
      })
```

Explained:
You add two arrayFilters x & y , so the query will be applied explicitely for any of the cases :

$in -> TRUE

$not $in -> FALSE

from the provided ids , in the example array list is ["1a1","1a2"].

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1kbgo1ukCt-)

Comment: Is there a way to just have the $in check provide the value for all nested documents?  I don't know the correct syntax but my assumption was you can do something like:

            $set: {
              "myAreas.isActive": {
                "myAreas.myOtherId": { $in: areas },
              },

Wouldn't $set loop through each nested doc in myAreas and populate the isActive prop based on whether the other nested field is in the activeIds array?

Comment: I tried the solution you provided and it works (just had to flip the $set values "FALSE" first, then "TRUE".    Just so I understand what's going on, my interpretation of your answer is:

First set the isActive in the nested array to a value so you can reference it in the arrayFilter.  Then depending on the current value, check if the id is in the list and that should return a true or false.  Why did you need two arrays?  That is the part I'm trying to wrap my head around.

Comment: there could be other options , but I think this one is best for the task ... , you need two arrayFilters to explicitely match the $in and $not $n cases , with only single arrayFilter you will match only the single case , and I understood you need to update the two cases at once  ...

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use the `$merge` stage.  As of v4.4 (Aug 2021), `$merge` can output back onto *the same collection as the input.*  This means we can use it like a giant update stage.
Consider this slightly larger input set:

```js
var r = [
{
    name: "Joe",
    note: "contains 1a1 and 1a3 so def in scope",
   myAreas: [
       {_id: '1a', isActive: false, myOtherId: '1a1', area: "Gaming"},
       {_id: '2a', isActive: false, myOtherId: '1a2', area: "Fishing"},
       {_id: '3a', isActive: false, myOtherId: '1a3', area: "Cooking"}
   ]
},
{
    name: "Bob",
    note: "contains 1a3 so def scope",
   myAreas: [
       {_id: '3a', isActive: false, myOtherId: '1a3', area: "Cooking"},
       {_id: '4a', isActive: false, myOtherId: '1a4', area: "Scuba"}
   ]
},
{
    name: "Tim",
    note: "no 1a1,1a3 BUT has >=1 isActive true so in",
    myAreas: [
       {_id: '5a', isActive: false, myOtherId: '1a5', area: "X1"},
       {_id: '6a', isActive: true, myOtherId: '1a6', area: "X2"},
       {_id: '7a', isActive: true, myOtherId: '1a7', area: "X2"}
   ]
},
{
    name: "Jane",
    note: "no 1a1,1a3 AND no isActive = true; OUT OF SCOPE",
    myAreas: [
       {_id: '5a', isActive: false, myOtherId: '1a5', area: "X1"},
       {_id: '6a', isActive: false, myOtherId: '1a6', area: "X2"},
       {_id: '7a', isActive: false, myOtherId: '1a7', area: "X2"}
   ]
}
];
```

Here is the pipeline:

```js
db.foo.aggregate([
    // We seek NOT to touch docs that need no touching.                            
    // The goal is to turn any myAreas.isActive = true if in activeIds.            
    // But we also want to turn things NOT in activeIds to false.                  
    // But if everything is false *already* (i.e. has NOT ONE entry                
    // of true) and does not contain activeIds, then that doc does not             
    // need to be touched.                                                         
    // Finding these candidate docs will not pinpoint the position in the          
    // array -- it simply filters down the candidate set.                          
    {$match: {$or: [
        {"myAreas.myOtherId": {$in: activeIds}},
        {"myAreas.isActive": true}
    ]}},


    // Use map to iterate over myAreas.                                            
    // The mongodb equiv of   doc[field] = true (or false)                         
    // is we take the doc ($$z) and overlay a new field.value                      
    // on top of it.                                                               
    // Notice that we use $project; we are cutting down the doc to                 
    // just myAreas (and _id, which always comes along) in prep for                
    // the $merge stage...                                                         
    {$project: {myAreas: {$map: {
        input: "$myAreas",
        as: "z",
            in: {$cond: [
                {$in: [ "$$z.myOtherId", activeIds ]}, // IF in the active list    
                {$mergeObjects: ["$$z", {isActive:true}]}, // THEN overlay true    
                {$mergeObjects: ["$$z", {isActive:false}]} // ELSE overlay false   
        ]
                }
        }}
    }}

    // Now, push back onto the input collection based on _id (fast).  The          
    // whenMatched = "merge" means the behavior is similar to $mergeObjects.       
    // Just the myAreas array (which is the only non _id field in the pipeline)    
    // will be merged into the existing doc:                                       
    ,{$merge: {
        into: "foo",
        on: [ "_id" ],
        whenMatched: "merge",
        whenNotMatched: "fail"
    }}
]);
```

This approach is both clear and straightforward and allows for plenty of other conditional updates.  It is less efficient when array fields like `myAreas` are very long and/or very big and only a very small subset of the elements have any changes because the whole field is merged back onto the DB.

Comment: I've got to assume here that the list length for myAreas will be in the 100s, maybe at most 1000 items.  At most, 5 records on this array will be set to isActive= True while the others will be set to False.  So if other ones in the array were set to True before for isActive, the approach should be able to go in and convert those to False.

Comment: @Ray  Apols; misread the question.   You write: "...if myOtherId is in the list of activeIds. If it isn't on that list, it should change the value to false."   So this is actually a full sweep of the collection, yes?  Leaving aside filtering by `name` etc., we need to examine *all* entries in `myAreas`; in fact, it's more like "set all to false, then if in activeId set to true".   ?

Comment: @Ray Answer updated to pick up things that need to be set true (activeIds) and docs where at least 1 true *might* have to be reset to false.